# bjam wih visual studio 2010

Tags: boost

ok, so I ran into problems with Boost under visual studio 2010, so I decided to rebuild it with bjam: such as:

```
bjam --toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete
```

After running bjam (successfully?) it created a new directory under boost_1_42_0 called: bin.v2
Inside bin.v2 is directory called: libs.
Two issues:
1. there's lot less libs under that new directory (about 13), the old directory libs has 88. Is it supposed to be like that or did something fail? 
2. the structure is somewhat different too.

What do I do with this exactly? Meaning, do I copy it over to the original libs, delete the old libs, try rebulding it with different flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as the message printed at the start of the build say, the libraries will be placed to `stage\lib`. The content of the `bin.v2` directory should not matter. Also, I don't think any release of Boost ever put any libraries under `bin.v2\libs` directly. I recommend you just use `stage\lib`. You can look at messages to see if anything has failed to build. Also,
you probably want to try 1.43 beta for best results with VS10.

Comment: thanks, but it does create bin.v2.
anyway, you're right it did put dll's under stage\libs. Do I need to move them somewhere or just leave them there?

Comment: you can leave this under stage\libs if you plan to update boost from and and rebuild in future. If you plan to stick with a single version for a while, you can move headers (the 'boost' directory under root) and well as all libraries from stage\libs somewhere else.